# How to connect to custom cluster with web3.js solana

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli

i've made custom cluster of solana.

I'm trying to connect to it with web3.js like this:

```
const url = solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl('http://x.x.x.x:8899/', false);
const solanaConnection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(url, 'confirmed');
```

but i'm getting this error:

```
Error: Unknown http cluster: http://x.x.x.x:8899/
```

Looking at the clusterApiUrl this only accepts :

```
export type Cluster = 'devnet' | 'testnet' | 'mainnet-beta';
```

is it possibile to change it?

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
const url = solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl('testnet', false);
```

return a string represents your url. please try just line below without using `clusterApiUrl()`

```
const solanaConnection = new solanaWeb3.Connection('http://x.x.x.x:8899/');
```

btw where do you want to use this